# Horizontal shaded frametitle in the CambridgeUS theme

Tags: beamer, color, themes, frame-title

I would like to modify (as simply as possible) the frametitle color of my frames but without changing anything else : I currently use the theme CambridgeUS and basically I would like to modify my frametitle color as it is in the Warsaw theme. I join you my current code and images to show you what I exactly want.

Wrong color but good theme :

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}

    \definecolor{rougefonce}{RGB}{180,1,1}
    \definecolor{bleufonce}{RGB}{30,1,135}
    \definecolor{vertfonce}{RGB}{0,90,0}
    \definecolor{bleuleger}{RGB}{220,220,235}
    \definecolor{rougeleger}{RGB}{235,220,220}
    \definecolor{vertleger}{RGB}{220,235,220}
    \definecolor{bleutitre}{RGB}{0,0,80}
    \definecolor{bleuroi}{RGB}{0,0,180}

    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
    \usecolortheme{whale}

    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg = bleutitre}
    \setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg = black, fg = white}
    \setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg = bleufonce, fg = white}
    \setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{bg = bleuroi, fg = white}
    \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg = black, fg = white}

    \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
    \title{Test with wrong color}
    \author{Bob}
    \date{\today}
    \institute{}

    \begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \begin{frame}{Wrong color}
    \maketitle
    \end{frame}



    \end{document}
```

[image: Wrong color]

Right color but wrong theme :

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}

    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
    \title{Test with right color}
    \author{Bob}
    \date{}
    \institute{}

    \begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \begin{frame}{Right color}
    \maketitle
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

[image: Right color]